# Particle system is not rendering

Tags: rendering, particles

Blender is not rending (EEVEE) the particles although its in the viewport. All the settings are enabled for the render.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Here's the link, its 15Mb compressed ZIP file:

https://easyupload.io/vaeyu7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not totally sure what is the reason, but if i decrease your very high amount of hair from 300000 (with 10x children) to 30000, it will be rendered.

[image]

Comment: Yes, unfortunately my system doesn't have enough processing power for particle system. The viewport did look nice, but couldn't render it. If you don't mind me asking, what GPU do you have?

Comment: M1 Mac, but mine didn't render your original settings as well